# What is the right way to use far direct jmp in emu8086?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I use emu8086 and **far indirect jmp** in `c2_s` works ok. But then in `c1_s` **far direct jmp** doesn't work. And it goes to `begin` in `c2_s` insted `p2`.

```
s_s segment stack "stack"
    dw 2
s_s ends 

d_s segment
    aa db 10  
    ab db 11
    addr dw p1,0712h 
d_s ends

c1_s segment
    assume cs:c1_s
    
    p1:
    mov bl, ab 
    jmp far ptr p2
    
c1_s ends

c2_s segment
    assume ss:s_s, ds:d_s, cs:c2_s
    
    begin:
    mov ax, d_s
    mov ds, ax
    mov al, aa

    jmp dword ptr addr
    
    p2:      
    mov ah,4ch                     
    int 21h 

c2_s ends 
end begin
```

I tried to use both:

```
    jmp far ptr p2        
    p2:
```

```
    jmp p2        
    p2 label far
```

but doesn't work anyway.

Comment: I am just guessing here, shouldn't you do something like `jmp far ptr c2_s:p2` to defeat the `assume` directive of the segment?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work - raises the error "(16) wrong parameters: `jmp far ptr c2_s:p2`"